# React - Passing Props

Tags: reactjs, react-props

Currently, it's giving me an error saying that isCompleted is undefined.

todo.isCompleted = todo.isCompleted ? false : true;

The above code is what's throwing the error.

The advice Im getting is to pass a todoIndex prop in App.js when you're rendering the Todo component.

Not sure how to go about doing that. Any pointers?

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import ToDo from './components/ToDo.js';

class App extends Component {
 constructor(props) {
   super(props);
    this.state = {
     todos: [
       { description: 'Walk the cat', isCompleted: true },
       { description: 'Throw the dishes away', isCompleted: false },
       { description: 'Buy new dishes', isCompleted: false }],
     newTodoDescription: ''
  };
}

deleteToDo(deleteToDo) {
  console.log(this);
  let newToDos = this.state.todos.filter((todo) => {
    return todo !== deleteToDo
  } )
  this.setState({ todos: newToDos });
}

handleChange(e) {
 this.setState({ newTodoDescription: e.target.value })
}

handleSubmit(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  if (!this.state.newTodoDescription) { return }
  const newTodo = { description: this.state.newTodoDescription, isCompleted: false };
  this.setState({ todos: [...this.state.todos, newTodo], newTodoDescription: '' });
}

toggleComplete(index) {
  const todos = this.state.todos.slice();
  const todo = todos[index];
  todo.isCompleted = todo.isCompleted ? false : true;
  this.setState({ todos: todos });
}


render() {
 return (
  <div className="App">
    <ul>
    { this.state.todos.map( (todo, index) =>
      <ToDo key={ index } description={ todo.description } isCompleted={ todo.isCompleted } toggleComplete={ this.toggleComplete.bind(this) } deleteToDo={() => this.deleteToDo(todo)} />

    )}
    </ul>
    <form onSubmit={ (e) => this.handleSubmit(e) }>
     <input type="text" value={ this.state.newTodoDescription } onChange={ (e) => this.handleChange(e) } />
     <input type="submit" />
   </form>
  </div>
);
}
}

export default App;
```

ToDo.js

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class ToDo extends Component {

  toggleComplete = () => {
    this.props.toggleComplete(this.props.todoIndex)
  }

  render() {

    return (

    <ul>
     <input type= "checkbox" checked= { this.props.isCompleted } 
    onChange= { this.handleToggleClick.bind(this)} />
     <span>{ this.props.description }</span>
     <button onClick={ this.props.deleteToDo }> X </button>
  </ul>

  );
 }
}
export default ToDo;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To pass the index to the `ToDo` component add another prop:

```
<ToDo key={index} todoIndex={index} ... />
```

and make sure that the component calls `toggleComplete` with that index prop, i.e.

```
class ToDo extends React.Component {
  toggleComplete() {
    this.props.toggleComplete(this.props.todoIndex)
  }
}
```

Also, you're mutating the todo object in your `toggleComplete` function, instead of:

```
todo.isCompleted = todo.isCompleted ? false : true;
```

Better do this:

```
const todos[index] = {...todo, isCompleted: !todo.isCompleted }
```

Or with `Object.assign`:

```
const todos[index] = Object.assign({}, todo, {isCompleted: !isCompleted})
```

I think Max Kurtz answer is also correct, the `this` binding seems to be problematic. Bind the `toggleComplete` function in the constructor or use arrow functions to make sure `this` doesn't bite you.

Comment: appreciate the help. I understand changing the ternary expression, but it gives me an error saying that index is an fatal unexpected token.

Comment: for your last comment about this, are you saying that I should avoid using it whenever possible and what would be an example of using an arrow function instead? Would replacing the this binding with arrow functions throughout the program be considered better practice or convention?

Comment: You can use the ternary, that's fine. You are not showing the ToDo component implementation, so I can only guess. I assume that it is calling the toggleComplete function. But that function needs the index of the todo and the ToDo component doesn't know that index because you're not passing it as a prop.

Comment: has been added.

Comment: Thanks! So it seems you're already passing `this.props.todoIndex` in the ToDo component when you call `this.props.toggleComplete`. But you're not specifying the `todoIndex` prop when you're rendering those ToDo components in the App component. On this line `<ToDo key={ index } description={ todo.description } isCompleted={ todo.isCompleted }... />`

Comment: so would i change this line?

Comment: toggleComplete={ this.toggleComplete.bind(this) }

Comment: Here I copied your code into this codesandbox and fixed the errors https://codesandbox.io/s/or1lm9wpq.